# Django translate tag with reverse url in text

Tags: html, django, internationalization, translation

I would like to translate a sentence with a word hyperlinked to an `url` inside the tags of `<p>`. What I am trying to translate in Django:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
```

I tried the following:

```
{% blocktrans %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This yields an error as it is not possible to have another '{%' inside the `blocktrans`.

```
{% blocktrans with link={% url 'register' %} %}
    <p><a href="{{ link }}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Second attempt is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757101/how-can-i-put-link-into-translation-label-in-django), but it does not work either.
Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like nested template tags:

```html
{% blocktrans %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

The `{% url 'register' %}` tag is nested inside the `{% blocktrans %}` tag. I do not think [Django's template engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/) would support that: it would attempt to parse the `blocktrans` tag and encounters another tag (`url`) inside of it, leading to an error, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036081/6309).

In the second attempt, it seems like you were trying to find a way around this by assigning the URL to a variable `link` within the `blocktrans`:

```html
{% blocktrans with link={% url 'register' %} %}
    <p><a href="{{ link }}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

But this also does not work because you are still trying to use a template tag (`url`) inside the parameter of another template tag (`blocktrans`).

I would first resolve the URL and assign it to a variable.
Then use that variable inside the `blocktrans` tag, inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746739/6309).

```html
{% url 'register' as register_url %}
{% blocktrans with link=register_url %}
    <p><a href="{{ link }}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

That way, you are not trying to nest template tags, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer but also for taking time to explain why it did not work, really helpful for learning! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using {% trans %}

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">{% trans 'Home Page' %}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but that breaks the sentence. The key point is, I need to translate the whole sentence together. And the translations are made automatically.

Comment: ```{% blocktrans %}
<p><a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy</p>
{% endblocktrans %}
```
When you run Django's translation mechanism, it will extract the text within the {% blocktrans %} block for translation, including the HTML structure and the URL provided by {% url 'register' %}. The translator can then provide translations for the entire sentence, preserving the HTML tags and the URL.

Comment: That's exactly the first thing I tried as shown in the post. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the {% blocktrans %} template tag for translation along with HTML tags

```
<p>
  {% blocktrans %}
    <a href="{% url 'register' %}"><strong>Register</strong></a> and be happy
  {% endblocktrans %}
</p>
```